# How can I determine a direction of force which is made by magnetic field and current with a wire? Fleming left hand rule seemingly not works at here

Tags: motor, electromagnetism

[image]

Please assume that the conductor of wire exists , and the current flows from below left to above right like shown in the above diagram.

As shown in the above diagram , the uniform magnetic fields are given .

I want to know the forces which act against the wire.

I tried to use the rule  of Flemming left hand .

But this rule seemingly only be able to be used as an angle between a magnetic field and a current , is a right angle .

I know the below formula .

$$ \boldsymbol{f}= l \left( \boldsymbol{I}\times\boldsymbol{B}  \right)  $$

Hence, the below is held .

$$  \Vert \boldsymbol{f} \Vert = l \cdot \left(\Vert  \boldsymbol{I} \Vert \cdot \Vert  \boldsymbol{B} \Vert    
\cdot \sin^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  \right)  $$

Just simply applying the above equation of magnitude can easily obtain the magnitude of total force which acts against the wire however how can I obtain the direction of the force vector?

I think the directions of it must be perpendicular against the directions of the magnetic fields but I don't know how to prove it so far.

I looked the page of wikipidea of cross product and found the below image .

[image]

Cited it from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)

Moreover how can I determine the vectors of forces  as the directions of the magnetic fields are reversed?

Comment: Why would you change to the second form of the equation and not stick with the vector form? Just use the vector form and all the magnitudes and directions pop out. Do you not understand how to directly work with  dot and cross product where you don't convert it to a form that contains a cos or sin?

Comment: https://efcms.engr.utk.edu/ef151-2019-08/m4/class-4-5/img/unit-vector-cross-product.png

Comment: Yes , I think I don't understand it so far.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you do. The conversion from vector for to magnitude form with trig functions is not the way the vectors are meant to be used. Leave it cross product form and treat it like a multiplication WHERE ORDERS MATTERS. treat i,j,k as variables (they are unit vectors with magnitude of 1 so do not change the magnitude when multiplied but have a direction associated with them).

Comment: The order the multiplication happens matters according to the image I linked and when you multiply (cross) two unit vectors together, it turns into the third unit vector with an associated sign depending on the order.

Comment: So \$3\vec{i} \times 5\vec{j}=15\vec{k}\$ while \$ 3\vec{j} \times 5\vec{i}=-15\vec{k}\$ and then something like \$(3\vec{i}+5\vec{j})\times(7\vec{k}+11\vec{i})=-21\vec{j} +0 + 35\vec{i} -55\vec{k}\$. The zero term is from the \$3\vec{i} \times 11\vec{i} = 33(\vec{i}\times\vec{i}) = 33(0)\$ as per your sin equation above (a vector shares has zero perpendicular component with itself and this is what a cross product finds.

Comment: So needless to say that we can determine that the direction of force is pointing from the front of the paper to the back of the paper(this display which we view)?

Comment: If so , the remaining problem is as the directions of the magnetic fields are reversed.

Comment: Be careful. What type of current is in your wire? Is it conventional current (positive to negative?) Or is it the actual electron flow (negative to positive)? In my experience it is probably conventional current which means the force is out of the page which means the blue arrows are correct. THe Lorentz force equation is the base form of the one in your post: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force. Notice the q, which is negative for electrons. But current direction is often labelled in term of conventional current, not electron flow.

Comment: At least it can be assumed as a steady current .

Comment: What? blue arrows are correct?

Comment: @bostondynamicslover yes, read the last comment.

Comment: So what you call the Left hand-rule in your equation isn't really...We actually use right hand-rule for the Lorentz force equation (and ijk cross product convention in general, look at the image I gave you and trace it out with your right hand on xyz cartesian axis) but then we keep in mind that for electrons, q is negative and that current flow direction is always labelled as conventional current, not electron current.

Comment: The reason you call it left hand rule in the equation you posted is that it only has I for current which is always labelled as convention current, but the Lorentz force equation requires a negative q for electrons and changing from right hand rule to left hand rule compensates for that. It's a pain in the ass, I know.

Comment: @DKNguyen Quoting from Matter & Interactions, 4th edition, page 810, ***Question**: "In most metal wires the moving charges are negative electrons traveling in the opposite direction. Explain briefly why the equation is valid even if the actual charge carriers are negative."* ***Answer**: "The electrons drift in a direction opposite to the conventional current, and their charge is negative. But it follows that the quantity, \$q\vec{v}\$, has two canceling minus signs and the equation in terms of conventional current works fine, even if the actual charge carriers are negative electrons."*

Comment: @DKNguyen , "it is probably conventional current which means the force is out of the page which means the blue arrows are correct"  , but its of the form j×i =-k, so direction of force should be in downward direction?

Comment: @user215805 You're going to have to tell me which axis labels you are using. They are unlabelled in your graphic so I just use the right hand rule. so that my fingers curl through the direction of qv (or I, if you will) first, then B and I look at which way my thumb points (that's what all that ijk business is actually doing), and then I negate it because q<0. That gives me pointing out of the page.

Comment: @DKNguyen , one of the component of current along y axis (j) ×direction of B in X axis (i).

Comment: @user215805 Oh, I see what you're trying to do. I'm cheating a bit because I know that only the portion of B that is perpendicular to the direction I matters. So I look at and change H in my mind to be a component running from NW to SE. If we are going to treat it as 45 degrees as drawn, then I = ni + nj and B = mi, where n and m are unknowns. I just picked them to give the proper angles. I x B then gives -nmk which does seem to point into the page. Hmmm yeah. I don't know what's going on there *scratches head*. Will have to take a fresh look tommorrow. It's late here.

Comment: Is the negative supposed to be thrown into the I x B after the fact just like the qv x B? That's the only difference I can see. In the Lorentz qv x B, I know to do it because the q is there. In I x B, I am not sure because just having I there would make me think all I have to worry about is conventional current, but that's obviously not the case.

Comment: @DKNguyen  , when we use qv×B ,v is in the direction of conventional current , in wire e (q= -e) is negative while we assume q positive  and  drift velocity of electron (which is also opposite to conventional current Ve=-Vq) , so again using Lorentz formula we get (-q) (-Vq) ×B =qV×B hence we got the same result from both equations

Comment: @user215805 Are you sure about that? Because that seems inconsistent with the diagrams 1-6 to 1-8 here https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_01.html#Ch1-S1 Hmmmm. EDIT: They seem to match up now. What was I doing a while back? I wonder if I was  mixing up the force exerted on the magnet vs the wire.

Comment: @user215805 Bah, that definition is even more confusing because now v isn't even the direction of the charged particle's movement anymore. It feels super wrong. That seems almost unjustifiable because all the layers the negation are obfuscating how it seems obvious that if you send positive charges in one direction, some force is produced and reversing direction or reversing charge polarity (but not both) will reverse the force

Comment: The force is **always perpendicular** to both the magnetic field and the current flow. The right hand rule tells you which way the force goes (since there are two perpendicular directions). If the current flow is not perpendicular to the magnetic field, the force is **still perpendicular to both**, but also weakened.

Answer (score 0):

$$  \boldsymbol{ F }_{} = \boldsymbol{I}\times\boldsymbol{B}   $$

$$  d \boldsymbol{ F }_{} = I \left( d \boldsymbol{ s }_{} \times \boldsymbol{ B }_{}    \right)    $$

Use these with right hand rule .